# How to returns true for a period and and edge for a given timer

Tags: typescript

Here are some tests that should return true

```
// not working version
const on_interval_lee = (period, life, life0) => {
  return life0 < life && ((life0 % period) <= period - 1 && (life % period) >= 1
)
}

// these logs should return true
console.log(on_interval_lee(4, 3, 2) === true)
console.log(on_interval_lee(4, 4, 3) === true)
console.log(on_interval_lee(4, 5, 4) === true)
console.log(on_interval_lee(4, 7, 8) === true)
console.log(on_interval_lee(4, 8, 7) === true)
console.log(on_interval_lee(4, 9, 8) === true)
console.log(on_interval_lee(4, 6, 5) === false)
console.log(on_interval_lee(4, 10, 11) === false)
```

I have an increasing timer that goes from 0 to 100, repeating values a couple of times like this: `0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 4 4 4 4 5 .. 100`

I am interested in the intervals that this timer changes value so I keep the old value of the timer to compare too.

Something like this:

```
  update(dt: number, dt0: number) {
    this.life0 = this.life
    this.life += dt
  }
```

I have a function that returns true for those changing intervals on a period t.

```
const on_interval = (t, life, life0) => {
  return Math.floor(life0 / t) !== Math.floor(life / t)
}
```

So when called in an update loop like this:

```
on_interval(4, 1, 0) // false
on_interval(4, 4, 3) // true
on_interval(4, 8, 7) // true
on_interval(4, 12, 11) // true
on_interval(4, 13, 12) // false
```

But I want a similar function but returns true for a given period and some edge like this:

```
on_interval2(4, 10, 9) // false
on_interval2(4, 11, 10) // true
on_interval2(4, 12, 11) // true
on_interval2(4, 13, 12) // true
on_interval2(4, 14, 13) // false
```

So this returns true for the 4th interval as before, but also one before it and after it returns true as well.

What is the math for doing this?

Comment: This looks like a lovely piece of Ctypescriptrust code. In all seriousness, don't tag random languages. If this question has nothing to do with C and Rust, then it should not be tagged with those languages.

Answer (score 0):

```
const on_interval = (t, life, life0) => {
  return Math.floor(life0 / t) !== Math.floor(life / t)
}

const on_interval_lee = (t, life, life0, lee: Array<number>) => {
  return lee.some(_ => on_interval(t, life - _, life0 - _) || on_interval(t, life + _, life0 + _))
}
```